# Как избавиться от desktop.ini?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10-64 при любом копировании создаёт бесполезный файл desktop.ini с содержимым : 
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic

... который вдобавок неудаляется.
Как избавиться от этого мусора ?

Answer (score 1):

Файл «desktop.ini» содержит конфигурацию текущей папки (например, её иконку). Поэтому, если вы удалите этот файл, конфигурация связанной с ним папки будет утеряна и приведена к виду по-умолчанию.

Вы можете попробовать удалить этот файл сторонним файловым менеджером (с удалением неудаляемых файлов мне частенько помогает FAR Manager).

Файл «desktop.ini» является системным и по-умолчанию скрыт. Если вы его видите в Проводнике Windows, вероятно у вас включено отображение защищенных системных файлов. Чтобы это исправить, откройте Проводник, в ленте главного меню выберите вкладку «Вид» и в области навигации вкладки нажмите кнопку раздела «Параметры». В открывшемся вложенном меню выберите пункт «Изменить параметры папок и поиска». 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В открывшемся окне «Параметры папок» перейдите на вкладку «Вид», используя полосу прокрутки, опустите бегунок вниз и в списке доступных параметров установите флажок в ячейке «Скрывать защищенные системные файлы (рекомендуется)».
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]